# Is bootstrap-5 working fine with everyone?

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

Tried using bootstrap in 3 different laptops during 3 different occasions and doesn't work at all,
Lined using cdns not locally on my machine.
( note, tailwind worked just fine)

tried linking it locally, still nothing seemed to work. also I tried every single version of bootstrap with it's respectable cdn yet nothing worked at all

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the CDNs you used, and where you put them? Bootstrap 5 works great.

Comment: We're not a discussion forum. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you used the correct cdn links? And in their correct order.

```html
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```